# SubModule move conflict on git pull

Tags: git, git-submodules

In the "FrameworkRepo" I moved a SubModule from framework/modules/Vendor/SubModule1/ (this folder was deleted) to framework/vendor/SubModule1/ (this one was added) in "ClientRepo", committed, and pushed.

In "ClientRepo" I pulled "FrameworkRepo" (merged). I am now getting a conflict: `Auto-merging framework/vendor/SubModule1
Adding as framework/vendor/SubModule1 ~a853d4bc829db59c0e4d8b4e857034124018a917 instead`

How do I resolve this?

Before anyone says it... I know I could just not add the submodules to the repo and just use `git submodule foreach git fetch origin --tags && git pull && git submodule update --init --recursive` in the "ClientRepo" but we want to control what version SubModule they use in case our FrameworkRepo is not ready for a newer version SubModule. Hope that makes sense.